# Ignore Pandas Dataframe indexes which are not intended to be mapped using map function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
index,name,score,attempts,qualify
a,Anastasia,12.5,1,yes
b,Dima,9.0,3,no
c,Katherine,16.5,2,yes
d,James,NaN,3,no
e,Emily,9.0,2,no
```

I am trying to use pandas map function to update name column where name is either James or Emily to any test value 99.

```
codes = {'James':'99','Emily':'99'}
dff['name'] = dff['name'].map(codes)
dff
```

I am getting the following output -

```
index,name,score,attempts,qualify
a,NaN,12.5,1,yes
b,NaN,9.0,3,no
c,NaN,16.5,2,yes
d,99,NaN,3,no
e,99,9.0,2,no
```

Note that name column values James and Emily have been updated to 99, but the rest of name values are mapped to NaN.
How can we ignore indexes which are not intended to be mapped?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace back one way to achiev it

```
dff['name'] = dff['name'].map(codes).fillna(dff['name'])
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the map function will apply the dictionary values to all values in the 'name' column, not just the ones specified. To get around this, you can use the replace method instead:

```
dff['name'] = dff['name'].replace({'James':'99','Emily':'99'})
```

This will replace only the specified values and leave the others unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

```
codes = {'James':'99','Emily':'99'}
dff['name'] = dff['name'].map(codes).fillna(dff['name'])
```

`dff`

```
    index   name        score   attempts    qualify
0   a       Anastasia   12.5    1           yes
1   b       Dima        9.0     3           no
2   c       Katherine   16.5    2           yes
3   d       99          NaN     3           no
4   e       99          9.0     2           no
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may be looking for [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html#pandas-series-replace) instead of `map`.

```py
import pandas as pd
names = pd.Series([
    "Anastasia",
    "Dima",
    "Katherine",
    "James",
    "Emily"
])

names.replace({"James": "99", "Emily": "99"})

 
# 0    Anastasia
# 1         Dima
# 2    Katherine
# 3           99
# 4           99
# dtype: object
```

If you're really set on using `map`, then you have to provide a function that knows how to handle every single name it might encounter.

```py
codes = {"James": "99", "Emily": "99"}

# If the lookup into `code` fails,
# return the name that was used for lookup
names.map(lambda name: codes.get(name, name))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
codes = {'James':'99',
         'Emily':'99'}
dff['name'] = dff['name'].replace(codes)
dff
```

replace() satisfies the requirement -

```
index,name,score,attempts,qualify
a,Anastasia,12.5,1,yes
b,Dima,9.0,3,no
c,Katherine,16.5,2,yes
d,99,NaN,3,no
e,99,9.0,2,no
```